vscode the window terminated unexpectedly reason clean exit code 0
I have an issue with Vs Code in ubuntu.
I am running Nuxt 3 application  with Node 22 ()
In the middle of the development it crashes as in the following picture.
I tried to reinstall vs code and also updating it to 1.95.3.
Vs Code:
Version: 1.95.3
Commit: f1a4fb101478ce6ec82fe9627c43efbf9e98c813
Date: 2024-11-13T14:50:04.152Z
Electron: 32.2.1
ElectronBuildId: 10427718
Chromium: 128.0.6613.186
Node.js: 20.18.0
V8: 12.8.374.38-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.11.0-9-generic

What might be the solution? Thank you very much!


I found online sources saying I should reinstall the latest Vs Code and use minimal extensions. But even after that the problem was not solved. My Vs Code still crashes.
But now I think I solved it by increasing Swap space from 2GB to 8GB.This did not happen at all after I increased the swap.
Hope this helps!
